# In Yeoman, how can I move a folder and force delete on the original location?

Tags: javascript, yeoman, yeoman-generator

I am trying to move a folder in Yeoman without asking the user to approve every single file in the move. I currently have the two following ways to do this, but Yeoman's documentation is horrible and I can not figure out if there is a parameter to force delete.

```
//First way
this.fs.move(sourceDir, destDir);

//Second way
this.directory(sourceDir, destDir);
this.fs.delete(sourceDir);
```

Both of these ways will copy the folder + contents just fine, but the old folder remains or it will ask me to approve every removed file. I need it to just force delete somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeoman doesn't allow you to move pre-exisintg files around without asking user confirmation. User trusts Yeoman to not mess up their applications in unexpected way, so that's why it'll ask confirmation.

Users can always select `accept all` changes or run with `yo generator --force` to skip validation.

Comment: Thanks again for your help Simon, thats the second time now lol

Comment: Hey Simon, also I work at Fossil. Is there anyway I can contact you directly for anymore questions or things that come up in the future? We have started using Yeoman in house and I see you are a contributor to it.

Comment: @Metropolis if you want to try dropping in and chatting with us, you can join our gitter channel https://gitter.im/yeoman/yeoman - But stack overflow is also great for questions as it makes them available to the next person with the same question.